# iOS VR build view not working (Google Cardboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

So I just used Unity (Version 2017.1.0f3) to build a VR app. I got the build ready in Xcode and when I run the build this is the view I get. The app does not run just the black screen with the line only going 3/4 of the way up the screen. Anyone experienced the same problem?

[image: Unity iOS build on iPhone]

Comment: This screen is actually a VR mode, so your app runs. There should be issue with rendering of your graphics but without any code it is hard to tell what is wrong. You also can try to move your device directing it in all directions (including up and down), you may notice distorted image somewhere on the screen. In this case the issue is with matrix transformations for eyes.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on where I should begin to look? The graphics worked fine in Unity.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience in Unity, so not sure that my suggestions can help. I had some problems with black screen too, but in my case the transformations to objects were applied incorrectly. Referring to the TreasureHunt example - there are headPoseInStartSpace matrix, then projectionMatrixForEye and eyeFromHeadMatrix. I've used only eyeFromHeadMatrix and it worked fine, but when I applied also headPose and projection matrixes - I've received black screen. I've fixed this by setting z-index of my objects to -0.1 instead of 0, because they somehow appeared behind the camera, I guess.